# Using logic AND to two byes for checksum calculations

Tags: logic, checksum

For a checksum calculation I need to use a logic AND (&&). For example,

```
byte a = 0xAA;

byte b = 0xCC;

byte c = a && b;    //Answer should give 0x88//
```

but I get this error:

Severity   Code    Description Project File    Line
Error   CS0019  Operator '&&' cannot be applied to operands of type 'byte[]' and 'byte[]

Comment: Use & instead (bitwise AND)

Comment: Can you give me an example please?